# Is there a relatively simple way to create a "view" of a Windows folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

The "view" is borrowed from DBMS, as in a subset by certain criteria.

I'm trying to copy about 200k files (in a few levels of folders) from one cloud storage provider (mounted as a Windows folder) to another using their official desktop client. The problem is the client has 2 arbitrary limitations:

1. a folder can not contain over 50k files;
2. only 100 files and folders can be selected in one go.

I can't reorganize the source, so is there a way to filter a Windows folder to work around that other than using search?

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: Which two cloud storage providers?

Comment: So you need to divide the files up into "chunks" where `count <= 100` and `TotalSize <= 50k`, right?  What's wrong with search?  Can you not initiate a copy from the `SearchResults` folder?  Or were you discounting it as too much "manual Labor"? Because it doesn't have to be -- **PowerShell** could do the "thinking" and exeecute a `name:(name1 OR name2 OR ...)` search in an **Explorer** window.  I've answewred a question liek that on here or StackExchange IIRC...

Comment: Keith (not sure if I can mention the correct user, so not doing @), Windows Search is not fine-grained enough for this because the names are not in any meaningful pattern. My current solution is creating symlinks using PowerShell.